# Adicionar enumerador a uma tabela em PHP

Tags: php, html, tabela-html

Queria acrescentar um enumerador numérico sequencial (1, 2, 3, ...) a nomes que são obtidos através de uma query.

O resultado final seria:

```
sequencial | Nome
-----------------
1          | João
2          | Pedro
3          | ...
```

O código que uso actualmente:

```
 echo '</div>';  
 echo'<div id="tabs-3">';
 $sql = "select * from Tabela where Campos";
 $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
 {
 echo '<li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>';
 }
```

Comment: Aonde você está criando o `<ul>`?

Answer (score 3):

Se for apenas adiconar o número da linha, crie uma variável que faça essa contagem:

```
 $linha = 1;
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
   //seu código...
  echo $linha .' - '. $exibe['nome'];
  $linha++;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltou os enumeradores na tag `<ul style='list-style-type: decimal;'>`

```
 echo "<ul style='list-style-type: decimal;'>";
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
    echo '<li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>';
 } 
 echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de usar a tag `<ul>` (Unordered List ou Lista não-ordenada) você usar `<ol>` (Ordered List ou Lista Ordenada).

Usando Lista Ordenada as suas `<li>`'s ganham ordem numérica, por exemplo:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item A</li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
</ol>
```

Irá imprimir:

1. Item A
2. Item B
3. Item C